# useTranslation not working on client component consumed by layout component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, next-translate

**versions**

- next-translate: ^2.6.2
- next-translate-plugin: ^2.6.2
- next: 14.0.3
- node: 18.17.1
- yarn: 1.22.19

**What happened?**

I'm using app router on nextjs
In a client component used on a layout, i use `useTranslation` (https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate). On server render, all translations is correct. But on client side the translation is not loaded.

The same component work well when used on page.tsx

```
// src/components/TestClient.tsx
'use client';
import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation';
export const TestClient = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('common');
  return <div>This is client component, translation value: {t('test')}</div>;
};
```

```
// src/components/TestServer.tsx
import useTranslation from "next-translate/useTranslation";
export const TestServer = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation("common");
  return <div>This is server component, translation value: {t("test")}</div>;
};
```

```
// src/app/layout.tsx
import { TestClient } from "@/components/TestClient";
import { TestServer } from "@/components/TestServer";
export default function RootLayout({ children}: {children: React.ReactNode;}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <h2>Inside LAYOUT</h2>
        <TestClient />
        <TestServer />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
// src/app/page.tsx
import { TestClient } from "@/components/TestClient";
import { TestServer } from "@/components/TestServer";
const Page= () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Inside PAGE</h2>
      <TestServer />
      <TestClient />
    </div>
  );
};
```

### **Screenshot of render from server (with javascript browser disabled)**

[image]

### **Screenshot of render from client(with javascript browser enabled)**

[image]

### **How reproduce?**

Github repository for this issue: https://github.com/zeckaissue/next-translate-issue-client-on-layout

Codesandbox for this issue: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/zeckaissue/next-translate-issue-client-on-layout/main

EDIT: This seems related to https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate-plugin/issues/75

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because Next.js handles server side rendering and client side Hyderation.

Make sure that your components and layout are SSR-compatible.

To Prevent client-side code from running during server-side rendering

```
'use client';
 import useTranslation from 'next-translate/useTranslation';

 export const TestClient = () => {
     const { t } = useTranslation('common');
     return <div>This is client component, translation value: {t('test')}</div>;
 };
```

Use dynamic imports for components that are primarily used on the client side

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const TestClient = dynamic(() => import('@/components/TestClient'), {
  ssr: false, // Disable server-side rendering for this component
});
```

Make `next-translate` library's `withTranslation` higher-order component for server-side rendering. This ensures that translations are preloaded on the server side before sending the HTML to the client.

```
import { withTranslation } from 'next-translate';

const TestServer = ({ t }) => (
  <div>This is server component, translation value: {t('test')}</div>
);

export default withTranslation('common')(TestServer);
```

Dependency

```
yarn add next-translate@latest next-translate-plugin@latest
```

Comment: I don't want to have client component render only in client side...